# How to insert Variables into C++

Tags: c++, mysql, database, insert, connector

Hi i'm using mysqlconnector to establish connection to database.
how do i insert a string variable to the database? i've tried to search online but found no method to fix this issue. appreciate ure help

```
string procedure, cardid;
procedure = "ames";
cardid = "one";

pstmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO database VALUES (?)");
pstmt->setString(1, procedure);
pstmt->executeUpdate();
delete pstmt;
```

i've tried methods like the one below but it doesnt work for me as well.

```
string x = "INSERT INTO database(pro, card) VALUES ('";
x += procedure;
x += "',";
x += cardid;
x += ")";
stmt->executeUpdate(x);
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what?

Comment: it throws an exception and states that the pstmt statement is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed a ' on this line:

```
x += ")";
```

Try:

```
x += "')";
```